# Groupby to Count Frequency of Unique Values in Set

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DF like this

```
   User      Dept     
    1        Cook
    1        Cook
    1        Home
    2        Sports
    2        Travel
    2        Cook
```

I want to count the unique users within each department:

```
   Dept      User
   Cook      2
   Home      1
   Sports    1
   Travel    1
```

Notice how the department Cook only has a count of two because even though three users were found in 'Cook', there were only two *unique* users

I have tried the following:

```
 df.groupby(['Dept']).count()  -- counts 'Cook' three times
 df.drop_duplicates(['Dept']).groupby('Dept')['User'].sum() -- over counts all departments
```

I know the answer is a groupby, I just can't seem to figure it out!

Comment: You're really close!  `df.drop_duplicates().groupby('Dept').count()` I think might be what you want.

Comment: Hi Dagrha, this method is still counting "Cook" three times instead of two.  I need the count of unique users in each department.

Comment: What about `.size()` instead of `.count()`?  Both methods seem to be working for me (py2.7, pandas 0.16.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `nunique`:

```
>>> df.groupby("Dept")["User"].nunique()
Dept
Cook      2
Home      1
Sports    1
Travel    1
Name: User, dtype: int64
>>> df.groupby("Dept")["User"].nunique().reset_index()
     Dept  User
0    Cook     2
1    Home     1
2  Sports     1
3  Travel     1
```

(Note that I used your example data, which only has one unique user in Sports.)

Comment: Ah yes, this worked -- forgot about using nunique!  so many different ways to skin a cat in python.  Many thanks!